# Opposite of an eponym

Tags: names, eponyms

What is it called when someone lives up to their name. Their name is Smith and they become one for example.

Comment: Why, a *mynope*, of course.

Comment: @DanBron reading about the *mynope* here - http://staggernation.com/mf/ - the film "Good Will Hunting" springs to mind

Comment: @MaxWilliams Holy crap, a *mynope* is a real thing? Well, I guess it makes sense.

Comment: Well, it's "internet real"

Comment: @MaxWilliams One day soon "Studies in Internet Reality" is going  to be a major in universities.

Comment: @MaxWilliams TVtropes calls this phenomenon, when applied specifically to titles, an "[E**pun**ymous Title](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EpunymousTitle)". Found that by going to your staggernation link, finding an example ("Poetic Justice: come on, her name is Justice, and she's a *poet*?") and then looking that film up in TVTropes to see what titular tropes it'd been tagged with.

Comment: "Studies in Internet Reality" might be closer than (even) you think!: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_anthropology

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"**Nominative determinism** is the hypothesis that people tend to gravitate towards areas of work that fit their name. It predicts, for example, that because of their names, the scientists Splatt and Weedon ended up as urologists."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism

Comment: Nice! A word for everything, we have.

Comment: Upvote. @DanBron: This is what I love about English

Comment: Splatt and Weedon? I'm missing something.

Answer (score 7):

You might consider the neologism [Aptonym](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aptonym)

> aptonym ‎(plural aptonyms)
>   A proper name that aptly describes the occupation or character of the person, especially by coincidence.

Comment: I think the spelling is 'aptronym' (but I've seen both)